# why is this javascript date an invalid date?

Tags: javascript, date

I have created a date in javascript so:

```
    var thisDate = new Date(); 
    thisDate.setHours(0); 
    thisDate.setMinutes(0); 
    thisDate.setSeconds(0); 
    thisDate.setMilliseconds(0);
```

According to Chrome debugger tooltip when I hover the mouse over the variable:

```
  Fri Mar 15 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Easte...
  > __proto__: Invalid Date
```

Comment: Works fine for me typing all your commands in at the console (Chrome 25.0.1364.172).

Comment: @Explosion Pills: I am having weird problems with code that uses `thisDate` and I mistook "Invalid Date" as an error. Thanks for the link.